# Secure Amazon S3 bucket to only allow facebook access

Tags: amazon-web-services, facebook, amazon-s3, facebook-graph-api, amazon-iam

I'm making use of Facebook's instagram messenger API to be able to send images to our users. In their [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/features/send-message), they specify we need to send them a url to the image. In my case, that url point's to a S3 bucket that has the image. Facebook has to have access to the ressource.

My question is; how can i make sure ONLY facebook's api have access to READ on this bucket?

AWS's iam policies allows my to whitelist some ips, or to filter requests base on Referer header or userAgent, but none of those seems reliable to me, as facebook has a wide range of ips (changing frequently) and referer/userAgent can easily be spoofed.

How is everybody securing their ressources?

Comment: Generate a presigned url!?

Answer (score 1):

Your back-end app can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.

Basically, when you want to provide the user (or Facebook) with access to a private file, your app can generate a pre-signed URL that is valid for a given period (eg 5 minutes). After that time expires, the link will no longer work.

Comment: This is precisely it. Done it this way and works great! Thanks for the anwser John